# Set pageCount in cakephp pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

Is there any way to set the maximum number of result or pages in cakephp pagination? I know I can get number of pages running

```
$this->params['paging'][<MODEL NAME>]['pageCount']
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? you can do this by using limit. what I mean is maximum number of result is in your hand.

Comment: But if I want to limit number of pages also, like I only want to display 10 pages with 25 results in each page but my results are more than 250(25*10) so in cakephp pagination it also shows page no. 11

Comment: I see so You want to customize your pagination blocks? e.g. 1,2, ...,9,10,11 ? OR you want to show only last 250 fields?

Comment: I want to show only first 250 results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not set pageCount in cakephp pagination.
I am not sure about that.

You can only get the counts in controller as well as in the CTP files:
Let model is "Client" then

In Controller:

```
$clients = $this->paginate('Client');
print_r($this->params['paging']['Client']);
```

In cakephp templates:

```
$counts = $this->Paginator->params();
print_r($counts);
```

out put:

```
Array
 (
[page] => 1
[current] => 20
[count] => 144
[prevPage] => 
[nextPage] => 1
[pageCount] => 8
 )
```

Removed the unnecessary elements from the out put array.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do that in your controller, you can put this variable

```
public $paginate = array(
    '<MODEL NAME>' => array (
        'limit' => 10, //limit is number of rows per page
//... other condition here
        )
    );
```

Comment: No I am not talking about number of result per page , I am talking about maximum number of result so I can limit the number of pages.

Comment: If that is the case, I don't think you can do that using pagination in cakephp